# Connecting 2 points in a geodataframe to create a series of LineStrings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geopandas

Having trouble finding the right solution here. I want to connect two sequential points in a geodataframe to make a line. I don't want to use groupby as I need to keep the data for each index and not necessarily change the shape of the gdf. I implemented the dumb solution of just iterating over all rows:

```
for index, row in gdf.iloc[:-1,:].iterrows():
    line.append(LineString([row['geometry'],gdf['geometry'].loc[index+1]]))
```

But this seems real bad. Is there a solution using vector operations?

Edit: Here is a simple working example:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString

newindex = []
line = []

Name = ['Abby','Delta','Foxtrot','Lupo','Alistair']
Lon = [-81.6000, -81.1955, -80.8000, -80.4273,-80.1000]
Lat = [23.5000, 23.8552,24.2000, 24.5350, 24.9000]

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Name'] = Name
df['Lon'] = Lon
df['Lat'] = Lat
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df,geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.Lon,df.Lat))
for index, row in gdf.iloc[:-1,:].iterrows():
    newindex.append(index)
    line.append(LineString([row['geometry'],gdf['geometry'].loc[index+1]]))

nds = gpd.GeoSeries(line,index=newindex)
gdf['LINE']=nds
```

I want to add a LINE column to the existing dataframe that is defined by just 2 points: The point in the existing column and the point in the next column. While this works, it feels super inefficient to me.

Comment: Provide some data and specify how your output should look like, that will help us to recreate and identify your problem.

Comment: When someone answer your question, what should you do -  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Using ternary Operators and list comprehension, the code can be written as:-

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString

Name = ['Abby','Delta','Foxtrot','Lupo','Alistair']
Lon = [-81.6000, -81.1955, -80.8000, -80.4273,-80.1000]
Lat = [23.5000, 23.8552,24.2000, 24.5350, 24.9000]

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Name'] = Name
df['Lon'] = Lon
df['Lat'] = Lat
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.Lon, df.Lat))

# Is this more efficient?
df['LINE'] =  [(LineString([[a.x, a.y],[b.x, b.y]]) if b!=None else None) for (a,b) in zip(gdf.geometry, gdf.geometry.shift(-1, axis=0))]
```

Print out the result with:-

```
df.info
```

and get:-

```
       Name      Lon      Lat  \
0      Abby -81.6000  23.5000   
1     Delta -81.1955  23.8552   
2   Foxtrot -80.8000  24.2000   
3      Lupo -80.4273  24.5350   
4  Alistair -80.1000  24.9000   

                                                LINE  
0  LINESTRING (-81.59999999999999 23.5, -81.1955 ...  
1          LINESTRING (-81.1955 23.8552, -80.8 24.2)  
2           LINESTRING (-80.8 24.2, -80.4273 24.535)  
3  LINESTRING (-80.4273 24.535, -80.0999999999999...  
4                                               None
```

**EDIT**

To see the result as a plot, try this version:

```
Name = ['Abby','Delta','Foxtrot','Lupo','Alistair']
Lon = [-81.6000, -81.1955, -80.8000, -80.4273,-80.1000]
Lat = [23.5000, 23.8552,24.2000, 24.5350, 24.9000]

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['Name'] = Name
df2['Lon'] = Lon
df2['Lat'] = Lat
gdf2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df2, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df2.Lon, df2.Lat))

gdf2['LINE'] =  [(LineString([[a.x, a.y],[b.x, b.y]]) if b!=None else None) \
                 for (a,b) in zip(gdf2.geometry, gdf2.geometry.shift(-1, axis=0))]

gdf2a = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gdf2, geometry='LINE')

gdf2a.plot(lw=[2,4,6,8,11])
```

Output plot:

[image: 4lines]